# Imagick::getImageInterlaceScheme is deprecated

Tags: php, imagemagick, imagick, interlacing

`Imagick::getImageInterlaceScheme` is deprecated but I can't find a way to replace it in the code.
I tried with `Imagick::getInterlaceSchema` but it returns different values for the same image.

Does anybody know what would be the proper way to replace this function calls?

Thank you!

EDIT: I also asked the maintainers directly - it turns out it will be un-deprecated in the next release: https://github.com/Imagick/imagick/issues/455

Comment: Where did you see that `Imagick::getImageInterlaceScheme()` is deprecated? It doesn't say anything about it [in the manual](https://www.php.net/manual/en/imagick.getimageinterlacescheme.php)? Does it throw a deprecation warning?

Comment: Yes, it doesn't say anything about it in the manual, but throws deprecation warning: `PHP Deprecated:  Imagick::getImageInterlaceScheme method is deprecated and it's use should be avoided`

Comment: I also asked the maintainers directly - it turns out it will be un-deprecated in the next release: https://github.com/Imagick/imagick/issues/455

Answer (score 2):

Not sure where you got that information, nor am I sure exactly how desperate you are, but if your JPEG is progressive/interlaced it will almost certainly  contain a `SOF2` marker of `0xff 0xc2`. If it is not interlaced it will certainly not contain that.

See p32 [here](https://www.w3.org/Graphics/JPEG/itu-t81.pdf).

For testing, you can make a regular JPEG with **ImageMagick** in Terminal like this:

```
magick -size 64x64 xc:black regular.jpg
```

And an interlaced one like this:

```
magick -size 64x64 xc:black -interlace line interlaced.jpg
```